# Increment list in PHP alphabetically

Tags: php, list, increment

I'm working on something where the user is generating a number of objects in a form. When they submit the form, I want to echo the results back to them in a list (very distilled summary of what I'm doing).

In PHP, I know how to increment something in the conventional manner (1, 2, 3), but due to elements in the UI, I want to increment the list alphabetically (A, B, C). How would I do this?

Working code incrementing the list numerically:

```
//LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS PASSED TO THIS PAGE FROM THE FORM
foreach ($waypoints as $key => $value) {
$current = $key + 1;
    echo "<p><strong>Waypoint #$current:</strong> $value</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can increment letters in the same way:

```
$letter = 'A';
$letter++;

echo $letter;
```

Comment: Try it and find out! I believe it then goes to 'AA'

Answer (score 2):

You can increment alphabetically using this code

```
 echo $letter = 'A';
 for($i= 1; $i <=25 ;$i++)
     {
     $letter++;
     echo     $letter;
     }
```

Comment: this one is useful for when working with spreadsheets and you need AA, AB, AC and so on, when you go past 26 it automatically does this.. nice

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
$current = chr($key + 65);
```

Of course, you'd have to work out what happens when `$key` reaches 26.

Answer (score 1):

Functions ord & chr should help you.

ord('A') will give you the ASCII value of 'A'

char(X) will give you the character for ASCII value X

print chr(ord('A')+1); // outputs B